# group by with interval of time in hive gives null output

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a dataset , which looks like following-

```
Name    Time
A   00:00:00
B   00:03:53
C   00:01:16
A   00:04:34
A   00:07:32
A   00:18:36
C   00:16:12
C   00:05:04
E   00:01:50
D   00:12:05
A   00:11:20
B   00:04:27
D   00:02:47
A   00:00:23
I   00:00:23
F   00:36:21
F   00:02:46
```

I am trying to divide the destination ,for each 6 minutes interval since 00.00.00
So the hive query I came up with-

```
select name,count(1),FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)/360) from csvlog GROUP BY name , FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)/360) limit 10;
```

And the output I am getting -

```
A   1062    NULL
B   8   NULL
C   4   NULL
D   6   NULL
E   6   NULL
F   5   NULL
G   1   NULL
H   2   NULL
I   7   NULL
```

NULL is the value , I didn't expect.
I am just 1 day old in Hive so I may be doing something wrong.
I was expecting time as a value .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that if I use substring, then everything works fine-

```
select name,count(1),FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)/360) from csvlog GROUP BY name , FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)/360) limit 10;

replace 
FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)/360)
with
floor((floor(cast(substring(time,1,2) as int)*60 + cast(substring(time,4,2) as int)))/6)
```

**or as GoBrewers suggested**

```
select name,count(1),FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time,'HH:mm:ss')/360) from csvlog GROUP BY name , FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time'HH:mm:ss')/360) limit 10;
```

Comment: You don't have to use `substr` just specify the format.  `unix_timestamp(time, 'HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: well just found that since unix_timestamp expects a bigint but HH:mm:ss doesn't give that , so values come in negative